# Kibana 5.1 link

Tags: url, kibana-5

We are having Kibana 5.1 and I would like to create a link to specific dashboard with filter parameter.

I've found out that in old version you added "_q" (as query) and parameter. But this is not working:
http://127.0.0.1:5601/app/kibana#/dashboard/Overview?_q=from:name

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yo need to create visualisation or dashboard, and filter the data as you want by click on the chart, when you finish, you need to press on the save button on the top navbar then press on the share button on the top, copy the link, and share it